# Longer pause in Balabolka

Tags: balabolka

Balabolka seems to have a limit on the pause length.
I am struggling to create a longer pause. I have been using SAPI tag

and tried to create fake sentences on which it will pause without success.
//comment..

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following tag

```
<silence msec="200000" />
```